# Build in Visual C++ without Microsoft extensions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, standards

I am trying to build a project in Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 disabling all non standard extensions.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <windows.h>
#endif
```

In Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> Language, I set "Disable Language Extensions" to yes (/Za).
However, building the previous code I get errors such as:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h(11527):
>   error C2467: illegal declaration of anonymous 'struct'

This means that the _MSC_VER macro is still defined, and "windows.h" has been included.

How can I include a file if and only if I am using Visual C++?

How can I set Visual C++ so that it compiles the code as Standard C++, marking all Microsoft extensions as errors?

Comment: as far as i know windows.h uses microsoft extensions

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697013/how-to-undefine-msc-ver)?

Comment: Go through your code base and make sure that you don't directly include any files that are not part of the standard library.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489326/za-compiler-directive-does-not-compile-system-headers-in-vs2010

Comment: windows.h uses heavily unnamed structs which are not allowed in standard C++ (see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253878/why-does-c-disallow-anonymous-structs-and-unions).  A workaroud could be to give names to these structs.  But you'd have to use these personal names to access the elements of the struct as well, which would change definitions compared to MS documentation.  And if you would want to be able to compile your code with and without /Za, it would be a #define-#ifdef nightmare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I include a file if and only if I am using Visual C++?

As you have already demonstrated, by checking `_MSC_VER`.

> How can I set Visual C++ so that it compiles the code as Standard C++, marking all Microsoft extensions as errors?

You can't. I'm not aware of any compiler that allows this. Things like predefined macros for compiler version are entirely allowed by the standard, so they wouldn't be disabled as "nonstandard extensions."

If you want to check that your program builds for other platforms, then build your program on other platforms. GCC and Clang will tell you what they accept far better than Visual C++ will :)

Comment: So maybe the best thing to do is to define my own DISABLE_MSC_EXTENSIONS.

Comment: @Pietro yes.  And if you'd like to be portable, better structure your code so to isolate platform dependent code and use MS extensions only for these.

Comment: What about this:  _MSC_EXTENSIONS

Comment: @pie: `_MSC_EXTENSIONS` is a [reserved symbol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers). You aren't allowed to use it, it is reserved for use by the implementation.